# window.open working on firefox not on chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, jwplayer, window.open

i am trying a clickable link to be open in a new window when i click on the flash player (jwplayer 5) here is the code:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function openwindow()
{
    window.open("http://www.example.com","mywindow","menubar=1,resizable=1,scrollbars=1,width=350,height=250");
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="javascript: openwindow();">
<center><div id="mediaplayer">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="player.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        jwplayer("mediaplayer").setup({
            flashplayer: "player.swf",
            provider:'http',
            file: "file.mp4",
            screencolor: "000000",
            width: "875",
            height: "480",
            plugins: {
            'timeslidertooltipplugin-3': {}
            }

        });
    </script>
</div></center>
</a>
</body>
```

This is working fine with Firefox but not in Chrome, in Firefox when i click on the player the new window open fine but in Chrome when i click on the player is not opening but if i click at the ouside of the player it's opening.

Any idea why it's not working?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you checked the developer console for errors?

Comment: Yes...But no errors...

Comment: Where is this running?

Comment: It's running on my localhost...

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest not having any inline javascript. You could replace the line:

```
<a href="javascript: openwindow()">
```

With:

```
<a href="#" id="linkId">
```

And add the function to your `script` tag. So it would end up looking like that:

```
<a href="#" id="linkId">
    <center>
        <div id="mediaplayer">
            <script type="text/javascript" src="player.js"></script>

        </div>
    </center>
</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jwplayer("mediaplayer").setup({
        flashplayer: "player.swf",
        provider:'http',
        file: "file.mp4",
        screencolor: "000000",
        width: "875",
        height: "480",
        plugins: {
        'timeslidertooltipplugin-3': {}
        }

    });
    document.getElementById("linkId").onclick = function(){
         window.open("http://www.example.com","mywindow","menubar=1,resizable=1,scrollbars=1,width=350,height=250");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Still not working in chrome i have to click outside of the player to get work...why when i click on the player the new window is not opening? Thanks anyway